# Some particular paths with strong operator topology taste

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $H$ be separable Hilbert space. We say the sequence $\{A_n\}$ of subsets in $B(H)$ has **DS** property if the following two items  hold:

1) $A_n$'s are all finite.

2) Let  $x$ be in $B(H)$. There exists a sequence $\{a_n\}$  converging strongly to $x$ where $a_n\in A_n$ for all $n$

Q. Does there exist any sequence $\{A_n\}$ in $B(H)$ satisfying in **DS** property?

Comment: Hint: [the finite rank operators are dense in $B(H)$ in the strong operator topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/269972/bounded-operators-on-separable-hilbert-spaces).

Comment: @Michael Lee, But it seems some thing is wrong! For a given an operator $x$ in $B(H)$, we may just make a net (not a sequence) converging strongly to $x$. Anyway, could you please say more how you made the sequence $\{A_n\}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This amounts to ask whether $B(H)$ is sot-separable.

Fix an orthonormal basis $\{e_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$. Let $P_n$ be the orthogonal projection onto the span of $\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$. Then $P_n\to I$ sot, and since $\|P_n\|\leq1$ for all $n$, it follows that $P_nTP_n\to T$ for all $T\in B(H)$. 
It is also clear that $P_nTP_n$ has rank at most $n$.

If we  write $\{E_{kj}\}$ for the matrix units associated with the basis $\{e_n\}$ (i.e., $E_{kj}$ is the operator $E_{kj}x=\langle x,e_j\rangle\,e_k$), then 
$$
P_nTP_n\in\text{span}\,\{E_{kj}:\ k,j\in\{1,\ldots,n\}. 
$$
Now the set $\text{span}_{\mathbb Q}\,\{E_{kj}:\ k,j\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$ is countable and, for any $T\in B(H)$, 
$$
P_nTP_n\in\overline{\text{span}_{\mathbb Q}\,\{E_{kj}:\ k,j\in\{1,\ldots,n\}}. 
$$
It follows that 
$$
\text{span}_{\mathbb Q}\,\{E_{kj}:\ k,j\in\mathbb N\}
$$
is countable and sot-dense in $B(H)$.