# Closure of the Set of Hilbert-Schmidt Operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, topological-vector-spaces, locally-convex-spaces

Let $H$ be a separable Hilbert space. What is the closure of the set of Hilbert-Schmidt operators on $H$ in the set of bounded, linear operators on $H$ with respect to the strong operator topology? A reference would be muchly appreciated.

Best,
Luke

Comment: I found the answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/269972/bounded-operators-on-separable-hilbert-spaces